# What kind of cloning/checkout is needed to delete a file from the entire Git history?

Tags: git

After reviewing a lot of similar questions on how to wipe out a file from the git history I finished with the following command:

```
# removes a given file from the repository entirely
git filter-branch --prune-empty -d /dev/shm/scratch \
   --index-filter "git rm --cached -f --ignore-unmatch gridspace_operational.in" \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

However, when I do this on a local clone of my repo (HEAD pointing to master) it changes things on this local clone but nothing happens on the remote repository. How can I apply the complete file removal to the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is important to understand how modifying your remote repository in this way will affect other users. If anybody else has `clone`d, `pull`ed or `fetch`ed from the remote you should carefully consider whether you actually want to make these changes.

Effectively, modifying the history of your remote will cause all other clones of the repository to be incompatible with the remote. If any of these are locally modified, or if other developers are actively working on the project, you will need to carefully coordinate your `push`.

If you really do want to make these changes, `git push --force` will cause the remote to be updated to match your local repository.

If the removed data contained private information (like passwords) it is very important that you also change all of those passwords. Consider them compromised.

Comment: especially if you removed the file since it contains passwords or other secret stuff, each developer having an 'old' clone still can access that file, since he/she has the 'old' history. Still if he/she pulls you changes from the central repo, the old history can still be accessed using `git refstat`

Comment: Good point, Jens. I have updated the answer to include the need to change passwords and such as well as removing them.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to `git push --force` to your remote for the changes to be reflected there.